# XSS и SQL инъекции

Tags: php, sql

SQL инъекции:

```
mysql_query("DELETE FROM `ban_ip` WHERE `min` = '".$_GET['delmin']."' AND `max` = '".$_GET['delmax']."' LIMIT 1");

mysql_query("INSERT INTO `menu` (`name`, `url`, `counter`, `pos`, `icon`) VALUES ('$name', '$url', '$counter', '$pos', '$icon')");
```

XSS:

```
echo "О себе:<br />\n<input type='text' name='ank_o_sebe' value='$user[ank_o_sebe]' maxlength='512' /><br />\n";

echo "&raquo; Общий доход: <b>".$dohod."</b> <br/>";
```

Объясните, пожалуйста, как исправлять и в чем ошибки?

Answer (score 2):

Везде где данные идут из гет нужно делать

```
mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['XXX'])
```

расмотрим пример:

```
mysql_query("DELETE FROM `ban_ip` WHERE `min` = '".$_GET['delmin']."' AND `max` = '".$_GET['delmax']."' LIMIT 1");
```

я вызываю url: http://mysite.ru/admin/?delmin=' OR `min` like '%' --//&delmax=

и в результате выполняется следущий sql запрос:

```
DELETE FROM `ban_ip` WHERE `min` = '' OR `min` like '%' --//' AND `max` = '' LIMIT 1
```

догадаетесь что сделает данный запрос ?

Answer (score 0):

По поводу SQL добавлю, что цифровые данные (когда вы заранее знаете, что должны получить число) - можно проверять на `is_numeric` и/или приводить к типу `int`.

По поводу XSS - [вот](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xss) ссылка